# RequireJS - dependency parameter vs in definition require equivalence

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Is

```
define(['a', 'b'],
   function(require, exports, module) { } );
```

equivalent to this

```
define(function(require, exports, module) { 
      require(['a', 'b'])
});
```

If not, how is it different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first bit of code should actually be

```
define(['a', 'b'], function(a, b) { } );
```

and the second bit as

```
define(function(require, exports, module) { 
    var a = require('a');
    var b = require('b');
});
```

When you use the second bit of code requirejs has to parse the function.toString() to find the require statements and add them as a dependency.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define